# Cannot control the order of asynchronous tasks using promise

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I am facing an issue while using promise to control async tasks in JavaScript. In the following code, I wanted to output 'first' before 'second'. I used promise then block, but it didn't work as I wanted.

I used `setTimeout` to create different time delay, so that I can control async tasks order no matter what. Can anyone please help me understand why the code is not giving the output I wanted?

Here is the code:

```js
let first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(console.log('first'));
  }, 30);
});

let second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(console.log('second'));
  }, 3);
});

first.then(second);
```

Comment: Once the promise is constructed, the train has left the station, so to speak... `first.then(...)` takes a callback function to be invoked when `first` has been fulfilled. It makes no sense to pass it a promise object.

Comment: try `first.then(() => second);`

Comment: Your real code does not actually use `setTimeout()` for anything - all you have is two asynchronous requests, and you want `first` printed before `second`, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that your code sample reflects your real situation, so I think it's not useful to solve the issue in your code sample.

Here is what I think you have:

```js
// a task that returns a promise and takes some amount of time
const task = (name) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(name), Math.random() * 1000));

// a function using the task result
const taskDone = (name) => console.log(name + ' done');

// two instances of that task, finishing in unpredictable order
var action1 = task('task 1').then(taskDone);
var action2 = task('task 2').then(taskDone);
```

Run the snippet a few times to see that the result order changes. All you want a way to ensure that `'task 1 done'` is *always* printed before `'task 2 done'`, even if task 2 finishes earlier.

The way to do this is to use `Promise.all()`.

```js
const task = (name) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(name), Math.random() * 1000));
const taskDone = (name) => console.log(name + ' done');

// set up tasks
var allTasks = [task('task 1'), task('task 2')];

// wait for results and evaluate 
Promise.all(allTasks).then(allResults => allResults.forEach(taskDone));
```

`allResults` will be in the same order as `allTasks`, so `'task 1 done'` will now *always* be printed before `'task 2 done'`.

If you only have two tasks, you can be more explicit:

```
Promise.all([
  task('task 1'),
  task('task 2')
]).then(allResults => {
  taskDone(allResults[0]);
  taskDone(allResults[1]);
});
```

Comment: I do think this answer contains useful information, but you have to admit it reads like a politician's response: _"Here's the answer to what you **should** have asked..."_

Comment: @Patrick I don't believe in "answering the question as asked" as the only rule to how this site works. People typically ask *because* they don't know what they're doing. And *"I want promise results to be printed in 'code order'"* is common enough a problem for people struggling with the asynchronous code on a conceptual level to make the assumption I made.

Comment: Sorry I failed to express my sense of humor, I didn't mean that part of my comment as serious criticism. I just found it a bit funny was all. Like I said, it's a good answer.

Comment: @Patrick Understood, no offense taken at all. My assumption could as well prove to be wrong, we'll see. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it to a function and create a closure and it will be called when you call it right the way.

```js
let first = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log('first'));
    }, 30);
});

let second = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log('second'));
    }, 3);
});

first().then(second);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that your promise constructor executor functions call `console.log()` before the promises are even fulfilled. Instead, you should wait to `console.log()` the values that promises are fulfilled with:

```js
let first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('first');
  }, 30);
});

let second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('second');
  }, 3);
});

first.then((value1) => {
  console.log(value1);
});

second.then((value2) => {
  console.log(value2);
});
```

Now for the matter of sequencing the output, you can achieve this by awaiting the fulfilled value of `second` only after awaiting the fulfilled value of `first`, rather than awaiting both of them at the same time:

```js
let first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('first');
  }, 30);
});

let second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('second');
  }, 3);
});

first.then((value1) => {
  console.log(value1);
  return second;
}).then((value2) => {
  console.log(value2);
});
```

Comment: This is an important point: "...promise constructor executor functions call console.log() **before the promises are even fulfilled**."

Answer (score 0):

If you start two promises parallelly which are resolved by `setTimeout` then there is no way you can control your logs order.

You need to establish some order dependency between the two to resolve them in order.

One way could be as follows:-

```
let first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log('first'));
    }, 30);
});

first.then(() => {
    let second = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(console.log('second'));
        }, 3);
    });
    return second;
})
```